# Count words of nested subschema field of mongoDB collecction

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working on data analysis of CV data of a large mongoDB collection. I try to count the absolute frequencey of words in the job title (jobs.jobTitle field in below schema).

The documents are structured like this:

```
{
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    jobs: [{jobTitle: 'software architect', company: String, ...}, {jobTitle: 'full stack software engineer', company: String, ...}, {jobTitle: 'javascript developer', company: String, ...}],
    ...
}
```

I would like to iterate over the entire collection and get an outcome like this:

```
[{word: 'manager', count: 3245},{word: 'engineer', count: 3102}, {word: 'software', count: 3021}, ..]
```

I tried the following aggregation:

```
db.cvs.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            words: { $split: ["$jobs.jobTitle", " "] }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$words"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$words",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }, 
    { $sort: { "count": -1 } }
])
```

Which results to the following error message:

```
$split requires an expression that evaluates to a string as a first argument, found: array
```

Can I concat the string values of jobs.jobTitle first to a string by using an aggregation? Or is there any other way to achive the expected result?

Comment: `{ "$unwind": "$jobs" }` as the first stage before `$project`. It's an "Array", so you need to *"flatten"* that before you can just access the individual strings.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks a lot. It directly solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the quick comment @NeilLunn

I would like to share the corrected query with everyone:

```
db.cvs.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$jobs" },
    {
        $project: {
            words: { $split: ["$jobs.jobTitle", " "] }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$words"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$words",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }, 
    { $sort: { "count": -1 } }
])
```